# Applying a class to a row that is added dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a table that adds rows dynamically with a button

```
<button class="table-add_line" onclick="addRow()" >+ Add Line</button>
```

Within that table, I have a searchable select input which works only on the first row but doesn't when I add rows. The first row is searchable while the others that are added with the button are just plain selects

```
$('.addRow').on('click', function(){
    addRow();
});

function addRow() {
  var tr = '<tr>' +

    '<td>' +
    '<select class="table-control chosen-select" name="coa_cli_id[]">' +
    '<option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true"></option>' +
    '@if($coas)' +
    '@foreach($coas as $coa)' +
    '<option value="{{$coa->id}}">{{$coa->name}}</option>' +
    '@endforeach' +
    '@endif' +
    '</select>' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td class="table-debit">' +
    '<input type="number" class="table-control" name="debit[]">' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td class="table-credit">' +
    '<input type="number" class="table-control" name="credit[]">' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td class="table-description">' +
    '<input type="text" class="table-control" name="descriptions[]">' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td><span class="table-remove-btn removeRow" onclick="removeRow()">X</span></td>' +
    '</tr>';
  $('tbody').append(tr);
}
```

Here are some photos

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

I want all the rows I add to be searchable.
I couldn't really find anything online.
I tried changing my code for the search many times. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably coming from youre blade code.

You should try to remove quotes that surrender your `@if`. 
I hope this will work.

```
function addRow() {
     var tr = '<tr>' +

     '<td>' +
          '<select class="table-control chosen-select" name="coa_cli_id[]">' +
               '<option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true"></option>';
               @if($coas)
                    @foreach($coas as $coa)
                         tr += '<option value="{{$coa->id}}">{{$coa->name}}</option>';
                    @endforeach
               @endif
               tr += '</select>' +
          '</td>' +
          '<td class="table-debit">' +
               '<input type="number" class="table-control" name="debit[]">' +
          '</td>' +
          '<td class="table-credit">' +
               '<input type="number" class="table-control" name="credit[]">' +
          '</td>' +
          '<td class="table-description">' +
               '<input type="text" class="table-control" name="descriptions[]">' +
          '</td>' +
          '<td><span class="table-remove-btn removeRow" onclick="removeRow()">X</span></td>' +
     '</tr>';
     $('tbody').append(tr);
}
```

Comment: If this not working, can you show the html of your first `<select>` please ?

Answer (score 0):

already solved it.   I added  $(".chosen-select").chosen() at the end of function addRow()

Thank you for all who responded.